# Xcode : textfield redirects to nib

Tags: cocoa, xcode, sdk, uitextfield, nib

I have an app that explains terms.  They are all explained in nib files.  For example, the word "car".
The user has to search for the word "car".

I want to have a text field.  In that text field the user can type the word "car" and it will go to the nib file : "car".  How do I do that?

**It's like app where you can type an question in a text field and it will answer you in a nib file if you write the question correctly.**

Comment: You really want a separate nib for each term? Think that one over a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) declare a new IBAction called lookForTerm: in an objrct (eg appDelegate) 
2) in the .m file add this method:

-(IBAction)lookForTerm:(id)sender {
UiTextField* field = sender;
if ([[field text] isEqualToString:@"car"]) {
Load your nib
}
}

3) connect in the interface builder the action with your textfield

Comment: Thankyou very much ! What option do I have to take : Touch up inside ?

Comment: use did end on exit. This will call your action when you press return on the keyboard.

Comment: I know why It fails.  Maybe you could help me ?  I have a home page and a mainWindow.  The plist says mainWindow is the main page.  I launch the app and all is ok.  But I want to make the Home Page nib as main page.  I change it in the plist and I run my app and it crashes... Could you help me please ??

Comment: I suggest you letting it like it is. Apple made this template so they want you to develop your application with their plans. It makes it just more complicated without sense.

Comment: Now the apps don't crash.  I wrote the code and all.  I launch the app and write in the textfield something and then it stays like that, notting happens